# WPF C# Insert to MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I'm creating a simple WPF app in C# just to view, insert, change or remove data from database. Viewing the data works fine, but nothing else does. Whenever I try to insert/change data, I get the following error:

"An exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in library.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`wpfdb`.`book`, CONSTRAINT `book_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `author` (`id`)) "

My DB (2 tables with 1 foreign key):

`CREATE TABLE`author`(`
id`int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`
firstname`tinytext NOT NULL,`
lastname`tinytext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `book`;
CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `author_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `year_released` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `publisher` tinytext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `author_id` (`autor_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `book_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `author` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`

My C# method handling the data:

```
public void DataChanging(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_enabledChanges)
        {
            string updateString = "";
            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case DataRowAction.Change:
                    {
                        int id = Convert.ToInt16(e.Row[0]);
                        string name = (string)e.Row[1].ToString();
                        string year_released = (string)e.Row[2];
                        string publisher = (string)e.Row[3];
                       // string author = (string)e.Row[4];
                        updateString = String.Format("UPDATE book SET name=\"{1}\", year_released=\"{2}\", publisher=\"{3}\" WHERE id={0}", id, name, year_released, publisher);
                       // updateString = String.Format("UPDATE author SET name=\"{4}\" WHERE id={0}", author);
                        break;
                    }
                case DataRowAction.Add:
                    {
                        //string author_id = (string)e.Row[4];
                        string name = (string)e.Row[1].ToString();
                        string year_released = (string)e.Row[2];
                        string publisher = (string)e.Row[3];
                       // string author = (string)e.Row[4];
                        updateString = String.Format("INSERT INTO book (name,year_released,publisher) VALUES (\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\")", name, year_released, publisher);
                        //updateString = String.Format("UPDATE author SET name=\"{4}\" WHERE id={0}", author);
                        break;
                    }
                case DataRowAction.Delete:
                    {
                        if (!(e.Row[0] is DBNull))
                        {
                            int id = Convert.ToInt16(e.Row[0]);
                            updateString = String.Format("DELETE FROM book WHERE id=" + id);
                            MessageBox.Show("Successfully deleted");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("No ID in the table.");
                        }
                        break;
                    }
            }
            if (updateString != "")
            {
                _db.Execute(updateString);
                Status = updateString;

            }
            LoadExecute();
        }
    }
```

Finally, the error shows up in this method:

`public void Execute(String sql)
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
                if (!(connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)) connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                throw ex; // error shows at this row
            }
        }`

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, it looks like your INSERT SQL is definitely going to fail. You set AUTHOR_ID to be NOT NULL, but you didn't include it in your SQL. That would definitely throw a FK constraint failure.

Your UPDATE and DELETE statements, if those aren't working, I would speculate are because your indexing is incorrect. Have you checked to see what value Row[0] is? Rather than indexing you should reference the Row by the string names, if that is available to you.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, to be honest it's not my code and I don't understand all the things, but I 'repaired' it and now I'm able to insert data into the db without getting errors, but I did something wrong, because it doesn't insert anything, the result is just blank. I did this: updateString = String.Format("INSERT INTO book (name,year_released,publisher, author_ID) VALUES ('name','year_released','publisher',1)"); did I miss something?

Comment: A hardcoded value of 1 may not be wise, but as long as an author exists with that ID the SQL itself looks alright assuming the parsing happens correctly. Can you set a breakpoint before the command executes and post what the updateString is at that time? What do you mean the result is blank? It inserts a row with blank values or does nothing at all? You could try creating the MySqlCommand after your connection state.

Comment: Yes it inserted a row with blank values but for some reason now it inserts the 'name', 'publisher' (without the apostrophes) - this happens when I don't fill any value in the box. When I fill the values, it inserts the same thing - 'name'... but twice (2 rows). I toggled the breakpoint and the value of updateString is: "INSERT INTO book (name,year_released,publisher, author_ID) VALUES ('name','year_released','publisher',1)"

Comment: What box? Your values are ('name', 'year_released', 'publisher' and 1)? I would expect them to be the values that were in the row. Since rows are being added your command is being executed, but the SQL statement is wrong if it inserts blank values. My guess is that just before the execution, your SQL actually looks something like this...  INSERT INTO book (name,year_released,publisher, author_ID) VALUES (\"\",\"\",\"\", 1) which is going to insert a blank row into your database except for the key back to author.

Comment: In the WPF box for values input, Well as I said I toggled the breakpoint and the values just before the execution is "INSERT INTO book (name,year_released,publisher, author_ID) VALUES ('name','year_released','publisher',1)" , it doesn't insert blank row anymore, it inserts the value "name", "year_released", "publisher" and "1", no matter what are the exact values (for example "John, 1990, isbn, 1") it just completely ignores what I type inside.

Comment: So assuming that your string formatting is working correctly, your row is being passed or read incorrectly. Does it say 'name' or 'John' at this point? string name = (string)e.Row[1].ToString(); What row is this method accepting? Do you have a "title row" of sorts with those values in it that's always being passed rather than the row you're editing values in?